# Hadoop Mapreduce Map Side Join

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce, inner-join

I have the following files:

**City.dat**

```
Andorra la Vella|ad|Andorra la Vella|20430|42.51|1.51|
Canillo|ad|Canillo|3292|42.57|1.6|
Encamp|ad|Encamp|11224|42.54|1.57|
...
```

**Country.dat**

```
Andorra|ad|Andorra la Vella|Andorra la Vella|69865|468|
United Arab Emirates|ae|Abu Dhabi|Abu Dhabi|2523915|82880|
Afghanistan|af|Kabul|Kabul|28513677|647500|
...
```

What I need to do is to do a Map Side Join to get the population (column 4 in City.dat) and name of each capital (column 3 in Country.dat) listed in the Country.dat file. So I get the basic idea. The join key of both files would be the city value (column 1 in City.dat and column 3 in Country.dat). This way I should get a table containing all the information I need with one line for every capital city.

But how exactly does this work in Hadoop? How do I tell Hadoop what is the join key in both files (I would first need to parse that out of every line wouldn't I?) All the code I found was just looking like this:

```
inner(tbl(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.class,
          "/user/cloudera/City.dat"),
      tbl(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.class,
          "/user/cloudera/Country.dat"))
```

This just defines the two files that are supposed to be joined. But how can I define the join keys and what I define as a record (in my case one line of each file is supposed to be a record)?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for wanting to do a map-side join instead of a reduce-side join?  You're making the assumption that one of the two files is relatively small (enough to fit in memory).  It would follow from this specific case that the other file would be relatively small, too.  It follows from that that you might as well skipp hadoop and just write a java app with a hashtable.  A normal reduce-side join would be more appropriate unless there's a specific reason you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I need to use Hadoop but I could also do a Reduce side join. Both files are smaller than 2Mb. What would be the advantage of a Reduce Side join?

Comment: I just read up on it and you're totally right. Reduce Side Join is what I should be using...

Answer (score 0):

Basically the map() method will take a record and you'll write it to the context.  The key would be a concatenation of city and country name and the value would be the entire line from the file concatenated with some indiction as to whether it's from file 1 or file 2.  Hadoop would do its stuff and the reduce() method would be passed each keys you wrote in the mapper and an Iterable containing all of the values written by map() for that key.  Basically this pairs the lines from file 1 and file 2 in the Iterable with an indicator of the source.  Your logic takes it from there.

To answer your specific question, you could read file 1 in the mapper's setup() method and store the file contents I'm memory as a hash table.  Subsequent calls to the map)( method for each line in file 2 would have access to that hash table in memory.  The downside is that the file has to be small enough to fit in memory and the setup() method will be called for each input slice.

Comment: Chris Gerken:can you modify the given solution for large datasets ??

Answer (score 0):

You could pass either of the files as Distributed cache and the other one as actual input.

For example say that `country.dat` is the smaller in size among the both types of inputs then have this in distributed cache.

Now, read this `country.dat` in the configure or setup method (new or old API respectively) and create a HashMap as desired(key it to the capital city) and then later use this HashMap as required in the map method to join the records.